# Image on input button disappears when clicked

Tags: html, css

I have a button with an image that links to another page when pressed. It all works fine, except when I click on the button it blanks out, and the image does not reappear until something else on the page is selected. The HTML is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="personalbutton" value="" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.ca'">
```

The personalbutton CSS class:

```
.personalbutton {
background-image: url(../images/buttons/buttonimage.png);
width: 175px;
height: 50px;
```

}

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: So what happens when you click on the button?  are you not redirected to another page?  if you are redirected, the button will no longer be there??!?!!?

Comment: The button does direct to another page, but the image blanks out immediately and it's just a bit jarring. As well, if you click but don't release it sits blank until something else is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a  tag of type 'submit' to create your button, try using the  tag and see if you still have the same problem.

```
<button class="personalbutton" onclick="location.href='http://www.google.ca'">Click Me</button>
```